# Menu bar not showing in Android Studio

Tags: macos, android-studio, macos-sierra

I have a problem with my Android Studio app on macOS Sierra.

It seems like the app is not really open, because usually, when an app is open, there is a dot under its icon in the dock, but on my computer there is none...

The true problem is that the menu bar options like "File", "Build", ... don't show up, and I can't access them. Instead I have the options of the next open app. Once again, it looks as if Android Studio were not open. It's very annoying because I can't use all the tools.

Except these problems, I can edit my code, I can launch an app on a device using a USB wire, etc. It's very weird, and I haven't seen any similar issues on the Web. I tried restarting the app and restarting my computer, none of these worked...

Have you ever experienced the same problem with Android Studio (or with any other app)?

Comment: did you solve this issue? Coz I am having the same issue.

Comment: Not yet, I tried a lot of things but none of them worked... Actually I can access all the tools using the search option, but it's annoying

Comment: I am assigning shortcut keys to the options from the menu and then using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by Apple. Upgrading macOS to 10.13.2 Beta 4 (17C79a) resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I face this issue everyday in Monterey, the menu bar just hides and doesn't show, happens with Android Studio only, solution is to expand the Android studio as a full screen widget and then shrink it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [IDEA-175658](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175658) this is a known bug in High Sierra. But it seems to be a bug of Java and not Jetbrains products.

The workaround by the time being is installing [Apple legacy Java 6 runtime](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572). I can confirm it works over here.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not using High Sierra yet, I'm on Sierra, so I don't think it's the same problem... Btw is it really recommended to install an old java version? I don't feel really enthusiastic about it...