# Android Studio upper menu

Tags: android-studio, macos-high-sierra

After updating to High Sierra beta, my upper menu bar disappears. I can't find a way to bring it back.

[image]

Here is how it's looking after the update:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the Java 6 Runtime https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Also duplicate of [Menu bar not showing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778860/menu-bar-not-showing-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the main tool bar, and choose Customize Menus and Toolbars,
expand the main menu and select item then click "add after" button then select an icon for the item, add all items in main menu separately.
The easiest way is to downgrade Android studio.

Comment: This is not the issue. Take a look at the screenshoot i added.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the upper menu by right clicking on the main tool bar, and choosing Customize Menus and Toolbars, then choose restore all defaults. I hope this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit **vmoptions** with `cmd + shift + a` and add this line :

`-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=false`

Restart the application.